# Can't encode content of keys from json

Tags: python, json

I would like to print every value that belongs to my `id` key in my `json` file. I'm using the below code to print the whole file:

```
import json

from pprint import pprint

with open('f:\Docs\testList.json') as data_file:    

    data = json.load(data_file)

pprint( data )
```

And here is the `json`

```
{ "clubs": [
    {
        "location": "Dallas",
        "id": "013325K52",
        "type": "bar"
    },

    {
        "location": "Dallas",
        "id": "763825X56",
        "type": "restaurant"
    }
] }
```

It works correctly, however I can't figure out the type of the `data_file` and `data` variables, therefore I have no idea how could I write a for loop to print the content. I'm really new to Python, but in pseudo code I would do something like this (if I assume `data` is an `array` (or Python list) of `dictionary` objects):

```
for dictionaryVar in jsonArray

    print dictionaryVar["id"]
```

or

```
 for dictionaryVar in jsonArray

        if dictionaryVar containsKey: "id"

            print dictionaryVar["id"]
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could show me the right way or give guidance, because I don't really have an idea. I checked the docs of the json module, but couldn't figure out what it really does and how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data_file` is a [`TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper), that is: a file object used for reading text. You should not care about it.

`data` is a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#dict). Dictionaries map key-value pairs, but you probably already know that. `data` has one key, `"clubs"`, which maps to a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#list). This list contains other dictionaries.

Your pseudo-code:

```
for dictionaryVar in jsonArray
    print dictionaryVar["id"]
```

corresponds to the following Python code:

```
for item in data['clubs']:
    print item['id']
```

Your pseudo-code:

```
for dictionaryVar in jsonArray
    if dictionaryVar containsKey: "id"
        print dictionaryVar["id"]
```

corresponds to the following Python code:

```
for item in data['clubs']:
    if 'id' in item:
        print item['id']
```

Comment: It's a really useful answer, I really like that you explained the data types too! Thanks Andrea!

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly simple, here is a quite explicit way of doing it (i made it longer so it's clearer for you, you could do this more efficiently)

```
import json

from pprint import pprint

with open('f:\Docs\testList.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    clubs = data['clubs']
    for club in clubs:
        # Use dict.get() here to default value to None if
        # it doesn't exist
        club_id = club.get('id', None)
        if club_id is not None:
            print club_id
```

Comment: What if `club_id` is `0`?

Comment: Thanks @andreacorbellini, I modified to check specifically for None.